# What is the Portable Class Library (PCL) Equivalent of Type.GetTypeCode

Tags: c#, .net, types, portable-class-library

What is the Portable Class Library (PCL) equivalent of the following full .NET code:

```
Type.GetTypeCode(myType) != TypeCode.Object
```

`Type.GetTypeCode` is not available in a PCL but the `TypeCode` enum is.

**Update - This Question is Different**

The possible duplicate does not actually answer the question. I am asking for an equivalent. I already know it's not supported.

Comment: fyi: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/2222 *Will be added back.*

Comment: The possible duplicate does not actually answer the question. I am asking for an equivalent. I already know it's not supported.

Comment: @MuhammadRehanSaeed I think you missed the part where it says that [Type.GetTypeCode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.gettypecode.aspx) **exists** in PCL.

Comment: @Nkosi It says 'Will be added back.'. Anyway, I have a PCL, it certainly does not exist.

Comment: I guess the documentation is wrong then. My mistake.

Comment: @MuhammadRehanSaeed first of all, please realize that the quote in question is from February - due to the fast moving nature of Core CLR, it might not be legit anymore - therefore I've added *fyi* :) secondly: the linked duplicate specifically answers your question: *Type.GetTypeCode() is supported in full .NET apps and non-Store portable class libraries, but not in Windows Store apps.*

Comment: My question is not if it is supported but what the alternative to the line of code above is.

Comment: Well, as per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.typecode(v=vs.110).aspx, it's the equivalent of making sure the type is a reference type (`!myType.IsValueType`) and that it's not one of the listed `TypeCode`s, i.e. `string`. That should do the job :)